# Modal solo abre con el primer boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

Estuve revisando la librería Material Design Lite, y tengo problemas con el modal, tengo dos botones y el modal solo abre con la primera, omitiendo al segundo.

```html
                            
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>
  <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>
  <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Confirm</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>
        If You delete your messages it can't be undone. Please Confirm to Proceed?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
   <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Confirm</button>
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>
  <script>
    var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
    var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los dos botones tienen la misma ID.

Lo que hace: **document.querySelector('#show-dialog');** es obtener sólo el primer elemento con la id "show-dialog" por lo tanto, el primer botón.

A continuación con **showDialogButton.addEventListener** lo que le estás diciendo es que cuando el primer botón sea pulsado pues se abrirá el modal.

Las id en html deberían ser unicas.

---

Editado:

- He añadido la ID **#dialog** al dialog
- He añadido las clases **.dialog-button** a los botones
- Mediante **querySelectorAll** obtengo un array con todos los botones que tengan la clase "dialog-button"
- Recorro el array y a cada botón le añado el mismo evento "click"
- Ahora cuando hagas cualquier click a algún botón que tenga la clase **.dialog-button** abrirá el modal

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="mdl-button dialog-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>
  <button type="button" class="mdl-button dialog-button">Show Confirmation Box</button>

  <dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="dialog">
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Confirm</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>
        If You delete your messages it can't be undone. Please Confirm to Proceed?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Confirm</button>
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>

  <script>
    var dialogButton = document.querySelectorAll('.dialog-button');
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
    if (!dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }

    fLen = dialogButton.length;
    for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
      dialogButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        dialog.showModal();
      });
    }

    dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si, pero que pasa cuando recibo los N botones, no puedo crear howDialogButton2 para cada botón.  Gracias

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer es solo un modal que identifique el ID.

Comment: He editado el código, mira si esto es lo que quieres